# Services and Repository in Clean Architecture

Tags: service, repository, clean-architecture

I use Clean Architecture in Asp.net Core.
My Layers are:
*UI
*Ioc
*Domain
*Data
*Application

In First I Define Model Classes In Domain Layer and Define An Interface For each Model.
then i implement the Interfaces in Data Layer. It's OK
After It in Application Layer I Define new Interface for Models and then implement Interfaces in this layer With the methods in Repository Classes in Data layer. In this layer i can use logic and condition while in Data Layer I Avoid From Logic.

is this Architecture Good?
and  when i have a simple Model With CRUD Operation I should Copy Interface in Domain Layer to Application Layer and then implement Services.
i confused for this copy paste in this Architecture.
what's your opinion?

[-Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPwqm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> "The purpose of a good architecture is to defer decisions, delay
> decisions." -- [Clean Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134494164)

It's hard to say if your design is good or not without knowing what problem you're trying to solve.

- If an architecture solves the problem, it might be good enough for now.
- If an architecture defers the decisions that you have make in the early stage, it's good.